# how do i get json responce from php below format?

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have two tables, in `yearselection` two columns are there and in `testtable2` three columns are there, based on first table id's using in second table., i want to display json responce as below using php, these two tables.

yearselection:

```
   id   year
    6   2014-2015
    2   2010-2011
    3   2011-2012
    4   2012-2013
    5   2013-2014
    1   2009-2010
    7   2015-2016
```

testtable2:

```
id   name    yearselection
1    test1        2
2    test2        1
3    test3        1 
4    test4        1
5    test5        2
6    test6        3
```

i want display like this in json format:

```
   {
    "2009-2010": [

        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "test2"
        },

        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "test3"
        },

        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "test4"
        }

    ],
    "2010-2011": [

        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "test1"
        },

        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "test5"
        }

    ],
    "2011-2012": [

        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "test6"
        }

    ]
}
```

mycode

```
public function actionArchives()
    {
    //echo $keyword=$_POST['keyword'];

        $query= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from yearselection ORDER BY id ASC")->queryAll();
        $arr = array();
        if(count($query) > 0) {

        foreach ($query as $queryElement) {

        $query2= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from testtable2 where yearselection='".$queryElement['id']."' ORDER BY id ASC")->queryAll();




        $arr[] = $queryElement;
        }
        }

        # JSON-encode the response
        $json_response = json_encode($arr);

        // # Return the response
        echo $json_response;


    //exit;
    }
```

Comment: How look your PHP code? Please share it.

Comment: First try this query:
`SELECT ys.year,tt.id,tt.name FROM yearselection ys
LEFT JOIN testtable2 tt ON tt.yearselection = ys.id
ORDER BY ys.id;`

Comment: added my php code above.

Answer (score 3):

you have write your query first like this

```
public function actionArchives()
{
//echo $keyword=$_POST['keyword'];

    $query= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT y.year,y.id as year_id,t.id as test_id,t.name 
    FROM yearselection as y JOIN testtable2 as t
    ON y.id=t.yearselection")->queryAll();
    $arr=array();
    if(count($query) > 0)
    {
      $arr = $query;
     // Now you run loop to change indexes of array,i.e.
      $count=count($arr);
      for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
      {
        $year=$arr[$i]['year'];
        $arr[$year]=$arr[$i];
        unset($arr[$i]);
      }
     // Now your array has index as your year column,
    }

    # JSON-encode the response
    $json_response = json_encode($arr);

    // # Return the response
    echo $json_response;


//exit;
}
```

Now once you write the above query you will get your data with columns **year,year_id,test_id,name**

Now you have take whole data in an array as you have done above in variable `$arr[]`(Not touching the `$query` varible to preserve query data).

Now you can do simply  `json_encode($arr);`

**Note**:-

> Please don't hit DB in a loop as if your loop length is suppose 100 then it
>   will hit DB 100 times. So you can apply JOINS in those cases so that
>   it will take data from 2 tables based on a single parameter.

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: where you want to display it i.e in table or anything else though and if you want to access json then you can also do it....

Comment: just i want to give api call for android above json format, just i want to print like that.

Comment: i have updated my answer.......please have a look....if still have doubt, we can do SO chat...